# Vector<Customer> C++, List<Customer> & Vector<Customer> Java

Tags: java, list, vector

I learned this piece of code in University, while learning C++.. and I later used the same thing in C#... but now I want to use it in Java... I have looked all over Internet for similar thing, but i dun even no how to phrase it so i get the correct results.

So umm please let me know how to do this is in JAVA and also let me know what is this way called??? I know What it does.. but i have no idea how it does it.. so mind explaining it as well...

C++ is the same thing as below except one DIFFERENCE look Below

```
C# if (Customers[i].delExecute(delIn) == true)

C++ if (Customers[i]->delExecute(delIn) == true)

Java ?? if (????????????????????????????????)
```

So here I go ill try my best to explain.
C#

```
Class called Customer with custId etc etc

List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customers>

    public void delCust(int delIn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Customers.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Customers[i].delExecute(delIn) == true)
            {
                Customers.Remove(Customers[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

bool delExecute(int delInput) {
    if (custId == delInput) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

OK right so the above code works

now I want the same thing with JAVA... anyone got any ideas how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (Customers.get(i).delExecute(delIn))
```

BTW, there is no need to say `== true` explicitly

Comment: Thank you very much.. hmm do you know what this way of using a List is called?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `Vector` is an out-dated class which you should probably avoid using. Instead, you should use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Either way, though, both are [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s, and thus implement [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) for *random-access*.

You can implement what you're attempting as follows...

```
if (customers.get(i).delExecute(delIn))
```

Note that `== true` is redundant, as it is effectively an identity (`true == true` is `true`, `false == true` is `false`). You should also avoid capitalized field names in Java.

Now, there is also a *preferred* way to do what you are attempting using an `Iterator`.

```
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customers>();

public void delCust(int delIn) {
  final Iterator<Customer> cursor = customers.iterator();
  while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    if (cursor.next().delExecute(delIn)) {
      cursor.remove();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

... coupled with:

```
boolean delExecute(int delInput) {
  return custId == delInput;
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. thanks a lot.. for taking the time.. and showing me the preferred way.